# optimizing mysql inner join group by

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I am trying to optimize the following query.

table seafood_tbl has 500 records

table dishes_tbl has 10,000 records

When I run this in PHPmyadmin it takes 20 seconds aka eternity to execute.

```
SELECT 
SUM(a.squid)
FROM seafood_tbl a
INNER JOIN dishes_tbl b ON 
   ( b.id_group = a.id AND b.choice =0 ) 
   OR 
   ( b.id_chef = a.id_chef AND ISNULL( b.id_group ))
GROUP BY a.id
```

I have indexes on every field referenced in the join.  I've run OPTIMIZE TABLE on dishes_tbl.

Here is the output from explains.

```
1   SIMPLE  a   ALL PRIMARY NULL    NULL    NULL    505 Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  b   ref_or_null choice_index,id_group_index,id_chef id_group_index  5   a.id    4   Using where
```

Is there something horribly wrong with my query or should I be looking somewhere else?

Comment: CAn you tell us more about the table structures and what data they hold? This seems to be a very complex way of doing something that may have a simpler alternative.

Comment: each seafood has x dishes and in the full query there are lots of big ugly sums and averages and inner joins on other things.  I stripped out everything until I found the minimal version of where its hitting the fan.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  SUM(a.squid) 
FROM    seafood_tbl a 
INNER JOIN dishes_tbl b
        ON ( b.id_group = a.id AND b.choice = 0 )  
            OR (ISNULL( b.id_group ) AND b.id_chef = a.id_chef) 
GROUP BY a.id
```

Create two index:

- INDEX(dishes_tbl.id_group, dishes_tbl.id_chef, dishes_tbl.choice)
- INDEX(a.id, a.id_chef, a.squid)

The column order int the two index maybe not the most optimal.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out using OR in a JOIN is a horrible idea.  I separated my query into 2 SELECTS unioned together, in each only joining on one condition, and it speed up the query by a factor of infinity.